# A hell of a day!

Tags: riddle

Some mistake me for a fan of Ronnie,
Yet I'm way older than this rookie.
Part of me like to fly and sting,
But the journey hurts my feet.
Don't be tricked into thinking I am fun,
Only the name of my doing will make you smile.
Come, you'll make my trip sooner or later,
But good luck crawling through them nine.

Who am I?

First hint :

> The answer is a person that existed

Second hint :

> the title is a big hint.

Added two lines to make it easier.

I enjoyed making this riddle so I am offering it to you, let me know if this is too broad, but there is one and only solution.

Comment: Is this musically inclined?

Comment: Not really, there's just a hint with music.

Comment: 'float like a butterfly, sting like a bee' ?

Comment: You got it right for this line !

Comment: Edited to make it a bit easier to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Incomplete, but are you

> Dante Alighieri

A hell of a day

> Dante's Inferno

Some mistake me for a fan of Ronnie,

Yet I'm way older than this rookie.

> He died a really long time ago.

Part of me like to fly and sting,

> Part of his name is "Ali"

But the journey hurts my feet.

Don't be tricked into thinking I am fun,
Only the name of my doing will make you smile.

> He wrote the Divine Comedy

Come, you'll make my trip sooner or later,

> Everyone dies

But good luck crawling through them nine.

> Nine circles of hell

Comment: Perhaps Ronnie refers to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ron_Dante

Comment: Nice one, ronnie refers to ronnie james dio who sang heaven and hell :)

Answer (score 4):

I'll try and guess:

> Muhammed Ali (or Cassius Clay)

Some mistake me for a fan of Ronnie,

> There is a singer called 'Mohamed Ali', who has a song 'Rocket'. 'The Rocket' is a nickname for snooker player 'Ronnie O'Sullivan'. You could easily mistake Mohamed Ali (the singer) for the boxer.

Yet I'm way older than this rookie.

> Muhammed Ali is born in 1942, the singer is from 1993. (and O'Sullivan from 1975), so he is way older.

Part of me like to fly and sting,

> 'float like a butterfly and sting like a bee' was used to describe his boxing style.

But the journey hurts my feet.

> Muhammed Ali was known for his incredibly fast foot work. Must hurt your feet in the long run. ([Youtube video for reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Fr1E1c1akI))

Don't be tricked into thinking I am fun,

> Reference to 'Comical Ali'?

Only the name will make you smile.

> Try saying the name and not end up with a smiling face on the last sound. I failed (but then again I've just had coffee, so all is well)

Also: There is a hint refering to music (as stated by the OP), I am however clueless how 'a hell of a day' is tied into this.

Comment: Nice try, but that isn't it. you got Mohammed Ali, where the Ali part is interesting for the riddle.

Answer (score 3):

I know it probably isn't but I want it to be

> Dorothy Day

Some mistake me for a fan of Ronnie,
Yet I'm way older than this rookie.

> Her name is very similar to that of Doris Day, an famous actress who made a couple of movies with Ronald Reagan. Doris, now in her 90s, is much younger than Dorothy

Part of me like to fly and sting,

> She was a radical and social critic in her younger years.

But the journey hurts my feet.

> Possibly a reference to her autobiography The Long Loneliness

Don't be tricked into thinking I am fun,
Only the name of my doing will make you smile.

> Because of the similarity of her name and Doris Day's some might not take her seriously, yet the impact of her work was great as was recently acknowledged by the Pope in including her in a list of four great Americans along with Abraham Lincoln, Martin Luther King Jr. and Thomas Merton. One might smile when thinking of how she helped to make the world a better place.

And the title, while a touch ironic and irreverent, certainly fits.

Comment: You guys are looking so far T_T nice try but it isn't it :)

Answer (score 2):

Is the person:

> Ali Saddiq

Some mistake me for a fan of Ronnie,

> Reference to Ronnie Chieng

Yet I'm way older than this rookie.

> He's been around longer than Ronnie.

Part of me like to fly and sting,

> Reference to Muhammed (Ali)

But the journey hurts my feet.

> He's had a long and rough path towards becoming a comedian.

Don't be tricked into thinking I am fun,
Only the name of my doing will make you smile.

> He's a comedian

Comment: No that is not it sorry